# iPhone: UITableView outlet dies when when pushed onto UINavigation controller stack

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView that's part of a navigation controller embedded in a UITabBarController. I set a IBOutlet to the UITableView in IB and on the first load, it's fine (i.e. valid address). But when the user drills down (i.e. puts the associated view on the stack and loads a new view) and then pops back up, the outlet to the UITableView is showing as 0x0, which I assume to be nil. I need to force a re-draw but the call to [myTableView reloadData] doesn't do anything. I assume that it's just sending a message to a non-existant object.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just set you outlet's value to nil somewhere in your code. Even if it was released it's value wouldn't be nil.